# Silverlight Copy Cell Content

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I need to allow a user to be able to copy cell contents from a DataGrid (Silverlight SDK).

Currently the Datagrid is bound to data by code behind.

The records are loaded into ObservableCollection, then to a PagedCollectionView and is set as ItemsSource to the Dataggrid finally

The problem I'm facing is that when I change

> IsReadOnly = "false"

for the Datagrid the user gets to copy the contents of the cell. But if by mistake they make any small change to the cell, then the changes are submitted automatically which is rising exception because the records are readonly.

So all i want to achieve is enable the user to Copy cell content but still keep it as readonly.

I don't mind if the cached record changes at the client but just don't want to allow the changes submitted to the service and rise unnecessary exceptions..

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a template per column using sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn that holds a read-only text box.

```
<sdk:DataGrid>
  <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="My Header" Width="80">
      <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBox BorderBrush="Transparent" Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

You should be able to copy out of the cells then.

Comment: This is quite good. Is it possible to apply this to all the columns (Text) as an attached template to the datagrid instead of each column?